# Wrapping text around figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I have the following command to display EPS figures and wrapping text around the figure:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{figures/flowchart}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

The problem is that the figure is displayed and text is wrapped not only around the figure, but also for all following paragraphs.
Any help?

Comment: I have difficulties understanding your problem. Testing your code, it seems to deliver exactly what you want.

Comment: The rest of the text after the image is also wrapped. It is not displayed in the full width of the page. Just half of the width of the page has text, the rest is empty.

Comment: You could try adding the optional argument to specify how many lines the wrapped figure should span, e.g. `\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{0.5\textwidth}` will make the figure take up 10 lines of vertical space.

Comment: @Torbjørn T
Nothing changed, just the 11th line after the figure is not wrapped !

Comment: Check that text in not really inside the wrapfigure environment . Please provide an [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) like in the Cristhian R. answer showing your problem.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: If you have an abstract, wrapfigure seems to break.

Answer (score 9):

I've extended your example to a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{gull}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Which is resulting in:

[image: Output]

As to my understanding, this is your desired outcome.  See [the LaTeX wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) for more documentation on this package.

Comment: I saw this example on the wiki of LATEX. It works on a separated file not in my document !!

Comment: @Abufouda Then it means that something else is wrong with your document. Unless you provide a [Minimal non-Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), we cannot help you.

Comment: Can I have non-rectangular shapes with wrapfig? I mean as the shapepar's cutout command. I'm looking for an easy solution to wrap text around nonrectangular shapes/images, not needing to define the position of every line explicitly.