# text alongside figure using minipage

Tags: floats, minipage

I need to place 2 images with captions in a minipage one below the other, in the second minipage alongside there is the description.
I cannot use `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`

I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88446/wrapping-text-around-figure), but the solution uses only one image, without minipage.
Hence seeking help here.

Here is my attempt.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{image1}\\
\indludegraphics[width=2in]{image2}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
 <some long text description>
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Use \captionof{figure} from the caption package.

Comment: thanks @JohnKormylo. I did that. I just posted a solution below!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are still a few problems with your solution, although some are probably due to not being complete (e.g. the geometry settings).  The negative \vspace is mostly needed due to the use of the center environment instead of \centering.  Also, \begin{minipage}[t] aligns the top baseline, which is actually the bottom of the first image.  One can use \raisebox to adjust that baseline.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption for fig 1}
  \label{fig1}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption for fig 2}
  \label{fig2}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: captionof]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it myself using the `caption` package

Here is the solution:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-0.55cm}
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{image1}
  \vspace*{-0.7cm}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption for fig 1}
  \label{fig1}
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{-0.7cm}
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{image2}
  \vspace*{-0.7cm}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption for fig 2}
  \label{fig2}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{0.75cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
  <some long text description}
\end{minipage}
```